# DataTable values cannot be accessed (even defined Table schema is not there)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

ASP.Net:

```
<asp:GridView id ="sampleGridView" AutoGenerateEditButton ="True" OnRowEditing ="sampleGridView_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit ="sampleGridView_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating ="sampleGridView_RowUpdating" runat ="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable("SampleTable");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack){
           PopulateGridView();     
        }
    }
    private void PopulateGridView()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Desgnation", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < src.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(src[i, 0], src[i, 1], src[i, 2]);
        }
        sampleGridView.DataSource = dt;
        sampleGridView.DataBind();

    }
    protected void sampleGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = sampleGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //Response.Write(src[1,0]+" "+ dt.Rows[0][0]);
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Name"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Desgnation"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["City"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    }
}
```

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position {Row Number} say 2. is the error in sampleGridView_RowUpdating at the line

```
dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Name"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
```

I tried following code commenting out the above error generating code

```
Response.Write(dt.Columns.Count+" "+dt.TableName);
```

Output is :
0 SampleTable

Why datatable values cant be accessed ?

Comment: Its a guess since you're sourcecode is incomplete buy did you remember to either call PopulateGridView or get the data table from somthing like a session variable on postbacks

Comment: datatable is not as a session variable. Its a member variable of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you manually populate a page's members you need to do on every request if you need it to persist between postbacks. This is often done using session state.

For example

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack){
           PopulateGridView();     
        }
        else
        {
           dt = (DataTable)Session["YourDatatable"]; //retrieve it from session
           sampleGridView.DataSource = dt;
           sampleGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
    private void PopulateGridView()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Desgnation", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < src.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(src[i, 0], src[i, 1], src[i, 2]);
        }
        sampleGridView.DataSource = dt;
        sampleGridView.DataBind();

        Session["YourDatatable"] = dt; //Store it for later

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try add row in table using this way  :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < src.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = src[i, 0];
        dr[1] = src[i, 1]; 
        dr[2] = src[i, 2];
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    sampleGridView.DataSource = dt;
    sampleGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: The problem is not with syntax of Add() method. The problem is theere is no column and also no row(means no data) in the datatable object.

Comment: try to declare as `protected` instead of `private` In DataTable object.and see what happening?